# Can't make visible/invisible values that repeat themselves in a RowField from a Pivot Table using a macro

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, pivot-table, vba

guys. I'm dealing with a problem for three days already and I found no answers. I'm trying to make visible certain values from a dropdown list in a RowField based on the month and year of the values.

```
For j = 2112 To i 'I don't need the values from 1 to 2111
dName = pvt.RowFields(1).PivotItems(j).Name
dt = CDate(dName)
If Month(dt) = month Then
    If pvt.RowFields(1).PivotItems(j).Visible = False Then
        pvt.RowFields(1).PivotItems(j).Visible = True
    End If
End If 
Next j
```

In my dropdown list I have values that are dates, it looks like this:

[] (Select All)

[]

[] 19-Dec-2012

[] 19-Dec-2012

[] 30-Dec-2012

[] 2-Feb-2013

[] 13-Feb-2013

[] 13-Feb-2013

[] 15-May-2013

[] 19-May-2013
etc.

My code will not make visible/invisible, for example, the second 19-Dec-2012 and I don't know why is that happening. For all dates that repeat only the first one will be made visible and the rest will be ignored.

Has anyone encountered this problem before?